# Excel: Counting instances of two matching cells

Tags: excel

I am trying to find the most efficient way to count the number of instances that a unique pair of cells appears.

Ex.

```
     _A____B__

 1. |Red | Blue 
 2. |Red | Blue  
 3. |Red | Green
 4. |Red | Blue
```

Total count of unique pairs = 2.

I've been using this formula and it's been giving me these results;

Formula: =IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A2=A2)*($B$2:$B2=B2))>1,0,1)

Results:

Columns

```
      _A_____B______C__

 1. |Red | Blue  | 1    
 2. |Red | Blue  | 0
 3. |Red | Green | 1
 4. |Red | Blue  | 0
```

The problem, is that I work with data sets that range from 50k - 800k rows and this formula causes Excel to become unresponsive and crash. I can only ever do 5k-10k rows at once and it still takes forever to process.

Is there an easier method that someone can help me with?

---

Comment: COUNTIFS is typically more efficient than SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: Make sure to not include the entire column in your ranges. Hard code the stopping point of your column

Comment: @user11156232 COUNTIFS over 800K times will also be problematic.

Comment: @ScottCraner, the COUNTIFS starts as a range of 1 row x 2 columns. It isn't until row 800K that the range has been expanded to 800K rows x 2 columns. You should be able to do much moe than '5k-10k' rows at a time.

Comment: @user11156232 you would think, but 800k countifs formulas even looking only one more than the one above will cause the countifs to fail.

Comment: Perhaps the correct question is not being asked. Do you need the ones and zeroes beside each pair or are you simply looking for the total number of unique value pairs? How many unique value pairs are typically in 800K rows?

Comment: You can use a pivot table, I believe?

Answer (score 0):

**An Array COUNTIF approach to identify unique data pairs**

*Note that this is an array function. This function requires execution with `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`*

> {=SUM(1/COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A,B:B,B:B)}

*In the code above, A:A represents the range of your first column of data, and B:B represents the range of your second column of data. COUNTIFS is not limited to just two criteria - up to 127 criteria can be included in the function.*

Although this is an array formula (potentially less swift than some other similarly classed solutions), the formula you are using now is certainly not desirable for your use case. While SUMPRODUCT is more powerful and versatile than COUNTIFS,the price paid for those advantages are increased calculation time when invoking the function on very large data-sets.

**Additional Considerations**

If you're on a build of Excel that has the Power Suite (PowerQuery, PowerPivot, PowerView) installed by default (Excel 2016+), or can install the Power Suite via the Add-ins interface (Excel 2013), I would suggest looking to solutions leveraging those tools to do what you're attempting to accomplish. Those tools are optimized for working with very large data-sets.